# Django expat issue

Tags: python, django

I am new to python and this Error when running django migrate:

```
from xml.sax.expatreader import ExpatParser as _ExpatParser
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/sax/expatreader.py", line 24, in <module>
raise SAXReaderNotAvailable("expat not supported", None)
xml.sax._exceptions.SAXReaderNotAvailable: expat not supported
```

Using Django 1.7 on Ubuntu 14.04 and python 2.7. Anybody have idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your Python install is broken, cf https://askubuntu.com/questions/161876/puimporterror-no-module-named-pyexpat and /usr/lib/python2.7/xml/sax/expatreader.py. The statement that raises is line 22 : "from xml.parsers import expat", and `xml.parsers.expat` just imports everything from the C pyexpat module at /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/pyexpat.so.

Comment: Thanks, saved my day... Re installing python using sudo apt-get install --reinstall python2.7  fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2):

For someone else who runs into this problem and reinstalling python doesn't work, I solved it by executing the following statement before running my management.py commands.

```
$ unset LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue. It was in a ceraint Django app, so I removed it. But next time I will try this! (reinstall did not help)

Comment: Awesome man, you saved my day, this worked for me, thanks for sharing.